# Compiling C++14 code with mutex on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, c++14

I'm trying to compile a program written in C++14 on the raspberry pi. It works fine on my local PC (macOS using Clang), but when I try to compile on the raspberry pi I get errors about several multithreading-related features of the standard library not being enabled:

```
In file included from /home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp:5:0:
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.hpp:118:10: error: ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     std::mutex lc_mutex_;
          ^~~~~
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.hpp:119:10: error: ‘condition_variable’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     std::condition_variable lc_cv_;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp: In lambda function:
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp:24:13: error: ‘unique_lock’ is not a member of ‘std’
             std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(lc_mutex_);
             ^~~
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp:24:30: error: ‘mutex’ is not a member of ‘std’
             std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(lc_mutex_);
                              ^~~
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp:24:45: error: ‘lc_mutex_’ was not declared in this scope
             std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(lc_mutex_);
                                             ^~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp:24:54: error: ‘lk’ was not declared in this scope
             std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(lc_mutex_);
                                                      ^
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp:56:17: error: ‘lc_cv_’ was not declared in this scope
                 lc_cv_.wait(lk);
                 ^~~~~~
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp: In destructor ‘Program::~Program()’:
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp:68:9: error: ‘lock_guard’ is not a member of ‘std’
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(lc_mutex_);
         ^~~
/home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp:68:25: error: ‘mutex’ is not a member of ‘std’
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(lc_mutex_);
... and so on
```

My g++ version is 6.3.0, and the command generated by CMake is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/c++    -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/lua5.3 -I/usr/include/jsoncpp -o CMakeFiles/runner.dir/src/program.cpp.o -c /home/pi/Development/TAoE-Runtime/src/program.cpp -pthread -std=gnu++0x -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread
```

I've already tried the following things:

- Setting `-std=c++11`, `-std=gnu++11`, `-std=c++0x`, `-std=c++14`, `-std=gnu++0x` and `-std=gnu++14`
- Adding `-pthread`, `-lpthread` and `-Wl,--no-as-needed`
- Using a different gcc version (4.7)

The two classes that cause the errors are `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable` and `std::lock_guard`. The code also uses `std::thread`, but that seems to work just fine.

Comment: When you said you tried setting the `std` options, you put them all at once or did your try each individually?

Comment: I tried them each individually

Comment: You *probably* either messed up  some include in your code or botched the libstdc++ installation. Impossible to tell for certain without [mcve] though.

Comment: If you're using an IDE, try and set the correct "language level", you should never have to put the `std` option manually

Comment: @BaummitAugen Indeed, the includes were wrong. For some reason, libc++ on macos doesn't require you to include the mutex and condition_variable headers when you already include thread

Comment: @Dirk That's always allowed, but never required to happen.

Comment: Why down votes? Sounds a reasonable question.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I downvoted as the question is not in an answerable state. Without OP presenting an MCVE showing they messed up their includes, how are you to write a definite answer for this? As it stands, the question is not just useless, but also off-topic (lacks MCVE).

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I provided that reason in an earlier comment already, btw. You could have just read that.